# Xamarin Binding Special Characters

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, localization

I am pulling some data from a remote DB and inserting them into a `ResourceDictionary`. My app will take the a key and get a value based on the chosen language.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Dictionary[, Something:]}"/>

<Label Text="{Binding Dictionary[&quot; Why&quot; - where what!]}"/>
```

So, if a user chooses Danish, the Label will use the key ", Something" and translate it to the Danish word.

The problem I'm having seems to be that I can't use special characters like "," and ":".

I have tried replacing those with Unicode and ASCII characters but it didn't work.

Comment: Try the shortlist given [here](https://www.dvteclipse.com/documentation/svlinter/How_to_use_special_characters_in_XML.3F.html) i.e. use `&#58;` for semicolon and `&#44;` for comma.